# Problems joining 2 kafka streams (using custom timestampextractor)

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having problems joining 2 kafka streams extracting the date from the fields of my event. The join is working fine when I do not define a custom TimeStampExtractor but when I do the join does not work anymore. My topology is quite simple:

```
val builder = new StreamsBuilder()

val couponConsumedWith = Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String(),
  getAvroCouponSerde(schemaRegistryHost, schemaRegistryPort))
val couponStream: KStream[String, Coupon] = builder.stream(couponInputTopic, couponConsumedWith)

val purchaseConsumedWith = Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String(),
  getAvroPurchaseSerde(schemaRegistryHost, schemaRegistryPort))
val purchaseStream: KStream[String, Purchase] = builder.stream(purchaseInputTopic, purchaseConsumedWith)

val couponStreamKeyedByProductId: KStream[String, Coupon] = couponStream.selectKey(couponProductIdValueMapper)
val purchaseStreamKeyedByProductId: KStream[String, Purchase] = purchaseStream.selectKey(purchaseProductIdValueMapper)

val couponPurchaseValueJoiner = new ValueJoiner[Coupon, Purchase, Purchase]() {

  @Override
  def apply(coupon: Coupon, purchase: Purchase): Purchase = {
      val discount = (purchase.getAmount * coupon.getDiscount) / 100
      new Purchase(purchase.getTimestamp, purchase.getProductid, purchase.getProductdescription, purchase.getAmount - discount)
  }
}

val fiveMinuteWindow = JoinWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10))
val outputStream: KStream[String, Purchase] = couponStreamKeyedByProductId.join(purchaseStreamKeyedByProductId,
  couponPurchaseValueJoiner,
  fiveMinuteWindow
  )

outputStream.to(outputTopic)

builder.build()
```

As I said this code works like a charm when I do not use a custom TimeStampExtractor but when I do by setting the StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG to my custom extractor class (I've double checked that the class is extracting the date properly) the join does not work anymore.

I'm testing the topology by running a unit test and passing the following events to it:

```
    val coupon1 = new Coupon("Dec 05 2018 09:10:00.000 UTC", "1234", 10F)
    // Purchase within the five minutes after the coupon - The discount should be applied
    val purchase1 = new Purchase("Dec 05 2018 09:12:00.000 UTC", "1234", "Green Glass", 25.00F)
    val purchase1WithDiscount = new Purchase("Dec 05 2018 09:12:00.000 UTC", "1234", "Green Glass", 22.50F)
    val couponRecordFactory1 = couponRecordFactory.create(couponInputTopic, "c1", coupon1)
    val purchaseRecordFactory1 = purchaseRecordFactory.create(purchaseInputTopic, "p1", purchase1)

    testDriver.pipeInput(couponRecordFactory1)
    testDriver.pipeInput(purchaseRecordFactory1)
    val outputRecord1 = testDriver.readOutput(outputTopic,
      new StringDeserializer(),
      JoinTopologyBuilder.getAvroPurchaseSerde(
        schemaRegistryHost,
        schemaRegistryPort).deserializer())
    OutputVerifier.compareKeyValue(outputRecord1, "1234", purchase1WithDiscount)
```

Not sure if the step of selecting a new key is getting rid of the proper date. I have tested a lot of combinations with no luck :(

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Does your custom extractor return the current timestamp? Also, look into `KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor#process()` to see what the processor does.

Comment: Thank you for replying @MatthiasJ.Sax . My custom extractor picks up the timestamp from the timestamp field of the events. I've found out the problem (have a look at my answer below) Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of that because I don't know how much you test your code, but my guess will be that :

1) your code work with the default timestamp extractor because it's using the time when you're sending record into the pipes as timestamps records, so basically it will work because in your test you're sending data one after another without a pause.

2) you are using the `TopologyTestDriver` to do your tests !
Note that it's very useful for testing your business code and the topology as a unit (what I have as inputs and what is the correct according outputs) but there isn't a Kafka Stream app running in thoses tests.

In your case you can play with the method `advanceWallClockTime(long)` in the `TopologyTestDriver` class to simulate the system time walking.

If you want to start the topology you will have to do an integration test with an embedded kafka cluster (there is one on kafka libraries that's working just fine !).

Let me know if that's help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying. I was working on this yesterday and I think I found the problem. As you said I am using the TopologyTestDriver to run my tests and when you initialize the TopologyTestDriver class it uses an initialWallClockTime, if you do not provide a value, the TopologyTestDriver will pick up the currentTimeMillis:

```
public TopologyTestDriver(Topology topology, Properties config) {
    this(topology, config, System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

There is another constructor that allows you to pass-in an initialWallClockTime. I've been testing this method but for some reason it does not work for me.

So to sum up my solution has been to create the Purchase and Coupon objects with the current timestamp. I'm still using my custom timestamp extractor but instead of hardcoding a date I am always getting the current timestamp and this way the join works fine.

Not fully happy with my end solution because I don't know why the initialWallClockTime does not work for me, but at least the tests are working fine now.

Comment: The initial wall-clock time should not have any influence IMHO. The join is defined on event-time and if you extract the timestamps from the payload, it should work. For using default timestamp extractor: This seems to work, because your input record will get timestamps from the factory that is initialized with wall-clock time, too. Overall, it does not seems to add up. I am also no sure what you mean by "I'm still using my custom timestamp extractor but instead of hardcoding a date I am always getting the current timestamp and this way the join works fine."

Comment: That's what I think at first @MatthiasJ.Sax but it seems that the wall clock time has influence in the way that the streams get joined (at least using the TopologyTestDriver). I noticed that when I was trying to find the problem and I return the currentTimeMillis in my timestamp extractor and the test started working. Anyway, I've pushed the test to my github repo so you can have look at better understand what I'm trying to explain: https://github.com/ardlema/kafka-streams-workshop/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/ardlema/joining/JoinTopologySpec.scala