# Kafka KStream-KStream leftjoin windowed with custom TimestampExtractor cause Skipping record for expired segment

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'am trying to left join 2 KStream (stream1, stream2) with a custom TimestampExtractor,
event if my 2 events are timestamped close enougth to each other, I get:

```
[my-app-client-StreamThread-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.AbstractRocksDBSegmentedBytesStore - Skipping record for expired segment.
```

For testing, I've tried not to use a custom `TimestampExtractor`, it works if my producer sends events fast enough and respects my window duration config.

Any ideas ?

I've check the documentation and I don't see limitation regarding custom TimestampExtractor when joining 2 KStreams ?

**Here is more details about the issue:**

My TimestampExtractor extract the timestamp from event payload:

```
public class EventTimestampExtractor implements TimestampExtractor {
    @Override
    public long extract(final ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> record, final long previousTimestamp) {
        final Event event = (Event) record.value();
        final long timestamp = = event.myTimestamp;
        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

Here is my application:

```
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, EventTimestampExtractor.class);
    
    ...
    
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();


    final KStream<String, Event> stream1 =
            builder.stream("topic-left", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),
                    EventSerde.serde()));

    final KStream<String, Event>  stream2 =
            builder.stream("topic-right", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),
                    EventSerde.serde()));


    stream1.leftJoin(stream2,
            (eventLeft, eventRight) -> {

                ... processing ...
                
                Data data = merge(eventLeft.data, eventRight.data);
                
                return data;

            },
            JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(1000)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(60000)),
            StreamJoined.with(Serdes.String(), EventSerde.serde(), EventSerde.serde())
    )
    .peek((key, data) -> {
        LOG.debug(key + data);
    });

    ...
    
    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
    streams.start();
```

After that, I inject using **kafka-console-producer** console, `eventLeft` in  `"topic-left"` and `eventRight` in `"topic-right"`, where:

- `eventLeft.myTimestamp = T (in ms)`
- `eventRight.myTimestamp = T+200 (in ms)`

My issue is, I don't get my log in `peek()` , I get that instead:

```
[my-app-client-StreamThread-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.AbstractRocksDBSegmentedBytesStore - Skipping record for expired segment.
```

When I display timestamp values in the `EventTimestampExtractor`, everything seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems duplicated with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739393/problems-joining-2-kafka-streams-using-custom-timestampextractor/53749441)

Instead of using **kafka-console-producer** console and hardcoded timestamps, I use an application that produce my data without hardcoded timestamp and it works.

I don't understand why it doesn't work with **kafka-console-producer** console, there must be some tricky behaviors around records internal and extracted timestamps.